# Relation Likes - Items - User, Parse UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uitableview

I have a doubt about what's the best way to manage the relation of likes and items (+User) in Parse, from a perspective of IOS UI TableViewCell.

Suppose we have an user, that can like many post and one post can be liked by many users. I proceed to create a Join Table between User and Post.

What do you suggest?
1 - Download all the items, and for every items get a count of likes and check if the user is in the list (But parse has some limitations on number of request).

2 - In the creation of the UITableViewCell, call a function (setLike(:NSIndexPath)), search for the data of this (cache the data), and set to the TableViewCell. (Limitation on number of request).

3 - Create Cloud Code, that read all the items, make the count and check if the user liked this items before.

Another option?

Comment: It is best to update the a like count on the post when you save the like, as you will typically save infrequently and read more frequently. You can use `incrementKey` to increase the like count safely. Also create an object that has a relation column for post and a relation column for user. Now you can easily find the users that like a post and the posts liked by a user.

Comment: it also depends how much likes do you expect, if it is less than 100 on post you can store the userID in arrayfiled as string. This have advantage that you know if the user liked or not if you download just post in single query but if there would be more likes it would download a lot of useless crap... I wouldnt use any count method because of the limits on Parse.com

Comment: Another idea is a beforeSave hook on the Like object.  Increment a counter property on the user who's post is liked.  Decrement on beforeDelete on a Like.